# Set uniform box height in CSS image gallery

Tags: html, css

This seems like a simple problem, but I can't crack it. I'm trying to set up a responsive image gallery much like the one demonstrated at [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_image_gallery_responsive). That gallery looks fine--until you change the length of the captions. Then the height of the boxes starts to vary, and the arrangement of the gallery gets all screwed up. How can I set the height of those boxes so they line up neatly, even when the captions range from, say, 2-4 lines long?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that you can do is, you can give a `min-height` and make it fixed height.

```css
div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 50px;
}
```

**Snippet:**

```css
div.img {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

div.img:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  min-height: 50px;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.responsive {
  padding: 0 6px;
  float: left;
  width: 24.99999%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .responsive {
    width: 49.99999%;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
  .responsive {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<h2>Responsive Image Gallery</h2>
<h4>Resize the browser window to see the effect.</h4>

<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_fjords.jpg">
      <img src="img_fjords.jpg" alt="Trolltunga Norway" width="300" height="200">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_forest.jpg">
      <img src="img_forest.jpg" alt="Forest" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_lights.jpg">
      <img src="img_lights.jpg" alt="Northern Lights" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="responsive">
  <div class="img">
    <a target="_blank" href="img_mountains.jpg">
      <img src="img_mountains.jpg" alt="Mountains" width="600" height="400">
    </a>
    <div class="desc">Add a description of the image here</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>

<div style="padding:6px;">
  <p>This example use media queries to re-arrange the images on different screen sizes: for screens larger than 700px wide, it will show four images side by side, for screens smaller than 700px, it will show two images side by side. For screens smaller than 500px, the images will stack vertically (100%).</p>
  <p>You will learn more about media queries and responsive web design later in our CSS Tutorial.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do 2 things.  Put both of these on the class applied to each block.

```
overflow-y: hidden;  //Or scroll if you want...
max-height: 400px;
```